# Can't get this statement to work

Tags: jquery, css, if-statement, element

I would like my element to show with position fixed only when `offset().top` is bigger than 300px

Here is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {   
    if ($(window).offset().top > 300) {
        $(".uparrow").css('position','fixed');
    }
    else {
        if ( $(window).offset().top < 300) {
            $(".uparrow").css('display','none');
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Please include HTML, and a snippet/fiddle too

Comment: I cant post a code but also i've got some errors in console http://imgur.com/a/o7EPG

Comment: be careful, your scroll position can be exactly 300, so check it with `<= 300`

Answer (score 2):

Your browser console is your friend. This will tell you right away what is wrong. In this case you would have received an error in your console `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined` - this would lead you down the path to fixing your issue.

You need `$(window).scrollTop()` not  `$(window).offset().top`

You also do not need your second if statement. This is covered by your previous else statement

I.E

```
$(window).scroll(function()
   {   
     if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= 300)    
     {
         $(".uparrow").css('display','inline-block');
         $(".uparrow").css('position','fixed'); // <- this is pretty pointless given you never change it when less than 300 pixels.
         console.log('I am fixed');
     }
     else 
     {
       $(".uparrow").css('display','none');
       console.log('I am hidden');
     }
  })
```

Comment: Thanks,now i don't receive errors but my element still has display:none

Comment: Added a little bit more - you never actually change the display css, you only ever add a position. There was no actual toggling. Not sure what you're trying to actually achieve, though the above code works.